# Scrape basic value from local text file

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, screen-scraping, extract

I'm looking to scrape the value from the below string.  Source is a local text file.  What is the easiest/simplest solution.  Assuming the least amount of programming know-how :)

```
<set label=\'Mon+Sep+10\' value=\'48644.54\'/><set label=\'Tue+Sep+11\' value=\'47912.02\'/><set label=\'Wed+Sep+12\' value=\'52219.28\'/><set label=\'Thu+Sep+13\' value=\'49854.88\'/>
```

Comment: You wanna read the content of a file?

Comment: If the source is a local text file then what is the issue, and why do you have web and screen scraping tags on the question?

Comment: what part would you like extracted? please provide exact expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea of the procedure to follow:

```
# Open the local file
fo = open(file-name)

# read the file - this assumes it is the first line
line = fo.readline() 

# close the file
fo.close()

# Use a regular expression to find the specific groups
import re
mos = re.finditer(r"value=\\'([\d.]+)\\'", line)

for m in mos:
    print m.group(1)
```

Gives:

```
48644.54
47912.02
52219.28
49854.88
```

The `mos` returned by `re.finditer` enables us to iterate through `match` objects, which is what the `for` loop is doing.  The method (function) of interest in a `match` object is `group()`, which returns the data in each *parentheses group*, that the data matched inside the `( )`.

Whether you want the loop in this form depends on what you want to do with the data afterwards.

The regular expression breaks down as follows:

`r"           "`         Always use a *raw string* with regular expressions, it is safer

`value=\\'       \\'`   Note that *two* \ characters are required.  a \ is a special character, but putting an extra \ removes its special meaning.

`([\d.]+)`               The parentheses groups the data matching this pattern.  The `[\d.]+` means "one or more digits (numbers) or dots".